# Changing types in flow.js

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've got an issue with regards to types that may change in a type definition.

If I am returning a heap typed like this:

```
type Test = {
  test: List<T>
}
```

but expect a function to do some conversion like this:

```
type Out = {
  test: Array<T>
}
```

is there a way to specify that I will be returning a Test type, only that this specific field test have been changed to an Array not a List?

Bear in mind this also using generics, so I don't know the shape of the types that are coming in or out, just that if a particular type is present, it will be converted to another type by the function, but the shape will remain the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an actual example you have where the analyzer fails to prevent a type error? Also JavaScript does not have a native List type, which one are you using?

Comment: @JaredSmith the list type comes from the definition provided by immulable.js. I guess in retrospect, defining an interface type and overriding the test value would probably be the way to go.